# how to update Select Attribute (add more option ) via Magento-upgrade-script

Tags: magento-1.9

i need some custom attribute on every category so i create a module and in `mysql4-install-0.0.1.php` i write :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$tagline  = array(
    'type'     => 'text',
    'label'    => 'tag-line',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => "",
    'group'         => "General Information",
    'visible_on_front'  => 1
);


$visible  = array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'is visible on homepage',
    'input'    => 'select',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0,
    'group' => "General Information",
    'visible_on_front'  => 1,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'
);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'tagline', $tagline);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'on_index_page', $visible);

$installer->endSetup();
```

setup work as expected and eveything is good, now i want to update the option of the `on_index_page` attribute so i create an other file name `mysql4-upgrade-0.0.1-0.0.2.php` in my setup folder, change the version form the config file and write this code :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();



file_put_contents("filename.txt", "data5"); // checking if file ever executed
$options = array ( 'value' => array(
                            '0' => array('no'),
                            '1' => array('Brands'),
                            '2' => array('Fruits'),
                            )
            );

//$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category','on_index_page','source','Hsn_Cat/Cat');
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category','on_index_page', 'option' , $options);



$installer->endSetup();
```

Magento run this file , as i do get the "filename.txt", but the option remain the same.

**information**
 1. the setup file is properly configured,and it execute without error.

2. while creating the attribute i use the `'source' =>
   'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean'` so i also test to undo that
   by doing this 
   `$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category','on_index_page','source','');`
3. i also tried to set the source to my own class  as i see that the `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean` have a function which return the array of option so i create a class like:

class Hsn_Cat_Model_Cat extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

```
public function getAllOptions() {

    file_put_contents("called", "im called");
    if (is_null($this->_options)) {
        $this->_options = array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Brands',
                'value' => 2
            ),
            array(
                'label' =>'Fruits',
                'value' => 1
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'No',
                'value' => 0
            ),
        );
    }
    return $this->_options;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use **`eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean`** as source model means,Your attribute only support ***boolean value means 0 and 1***.

As your want to use Custom source then model Then using source model,you need to `update source model` as you have created.

```
<?php
$installer = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','default_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute(
    'catalog_category',
    'on_index_page',
    'source_model', //a.o.t. 'source'
    '[YOUR_MODULE_MODEl_Prefix]/cat'
);

$installer->endSetup();
```

**Also you need to change  source model extends class**

`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` to `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`

```
<?php 
class Hsn_Cat_Model_Cat extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract{

    public function getAllOptions() {

        file_put_contents("called", "im called");
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'Brands',
                    'value' => 2
                ),
                array(
                    'label' =>'Fruits',
                    'value' => 1
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'No',
                    'value' => 0
                ),
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }


}
```